# rpy2: how to convert str vector into numeric vector

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Anyone know how to convert str vector in rpy2 to a numeric vector?

```
r('x_num = as.numeric(x)')
```

works, but x_num is not in the python environment. I can't call it from python.

I tried:

```
x_num = base.as_numeric(x)
r('class(x_num)')
```

which shows:

```
'<StrVector - Python:0x7fe602a54d88 / R:0xa06bb28>
[str]'
```

The reason why I want to do this is because, when I pass a numpy array to robjects.FloatVector, the class of the object is str vector, which causes problems for my further analysis.
e.g.

```
x = pd.read_csv('x.csv', index_col=0).values.flatten()
x_ro = robjects.FloatVector(x)
r('class(x_ro)')
'<StrVector - Python:0x7fe605062098 / R:0xa16c158>
[str]'
```

Thank you very much!

edit:
I've already added x_ro to the env. I forgot to copy it here

```
robjects.globalenv["x_ro"] = x_ro
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to your 1st problem, if the `x_num` variable is in the format you want in the R environment, you can get its *view* in python using the `numpy.asarray()` method (as stated in the [documentation](http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/numpy.html)), so changes you could made to this array in python will also act on the underlying R vector :

```
my_view = numpy.asarray(r("x_num"))
```

It can also be done automatically if you enter these line of code :

```
from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri
numpy2ri.activate()
```

So calling `r("x_num")` should return a numpy array if possible.

---

Also in your last snippet of code, are you sure that this is the "same" `x_ro` object, as you are not setting it in the R environnement ?
I guess you should do something like :

```
x_ro = robjects.FloatVector(x)
robjects.globalenv["x_ro"] = x_ro
```

then try again `r('class(x_ro)')` and see if you have the correct output.

Comment: thanks! for the second question, I actually add x_ro to the env, I forgot to copy it here. The class of x_ro is str vector still. For the fiirst question, I want to find a way to force the str vector into float vector in python through rpy2 instead of using `r('')`. but it doesn't work.

Comment: No need to bind an rpy2 object to a symbol in the R `globalenv` to know its class in R. Just do `tuple(x_ro.rclass)`.

Comment: @lgautier good catch (in fact i was most trying to emphasis the fact that the OP was testing its class in R, from a rpy2 object, without having originally (question has been edited), explicitly bind theses 2 objects, which could have been easily omitted by using the same variables names for example.

Answer (score 1):

It easier to identify an issue with a fully working example. Without it I am tempted to say that it is working as expected.

```
In [1]: import rpy2.robjects as ro

In [2]: ro.vectors.FloatVector((1,2,3,4,5))
Out[2]: 
<FloatVector - Python:0x7f3541c68788 / R:0x3541468>
[1.000000, 2.000000, 3.000000, 4.000000, 5.000000]

In [3]: ro.vectors.FloatVector(('1','2','3','4','5'))
Out[3]: 
<FloatVector - Python:0x7f353bff7d88 / R:0x3541398>
[1.000000, 2.000000, 3.000000, 4.000000, 5.000000]

In [4]: ro.vectors.FloatVector(('1','2','3','a','5'))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-263bdc61f184> in <module>()
----> 1 ro.vectors.FloatVector(('1','2','3','a','5'))

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/vectors.py in __init__(self, obj)
    454 
    455     def __init__(self, obj):
--> 456         obj = FloatSexpVector(obj)
    457         super(FloatVector, self).__init__(obj)
    458 

ValueError: Error while trying to convert element 3 to a double.

In [5]: ro.vectors.FloatVector(ro.vectors.StrVector(('1','2','3','a','5')))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-26578834d7ec> in <module>()
----> 1 ro.vectors.FloatVector(ro.vectors.StrVector(('1','2','3','a','5')))

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/vectors.py in __init__(self, obj)
    454 
    455     def __init__(self, obj):
--> 456         obj = FloatSexpVector(obj)
    457         super(FloatVector, self).__init__(obj)
    458 

ValueError: Invalid SEXP type '16' (should be 14).
```

Having established that we are able to build R vectors of float from Python, we can look at whether binding it to a symbol in R and accessing that object from R makes any difference. It does not:

```
In [1]: import rpy2.robjects as ro

In [2]: v = ro.vectors.FloatVector((1,2,3,4,5))

In [3]: ro.globalenv['v'] = v

In [4]: ro.r("print(v)")
[1]
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5


Out[4]: 
<FloatVector - Python:0x7fb4791e5f08 / R:0x2f7eed0>
[1.000000, 2.000000, 3.000000, 4.000000, 5.000000]

In [5]: ro.r("class(v)")
Out[5]: 
<StrVector - Python:0x7fb4791e5548 / R:0x2d02658>
['numeric']
```

Comment: it shows FloatVectors as you did if just print out the vector. But when I do `r('class(FloatVector))`, it shows str vector.

Comment: Same (see added second part in the answer). Without a self-contained example demonstrating the issue, it will be hard to convince me that there is one. Not saying there is not one, but saying that I am unable to reproduce one.